# Adding an HTML element to an AJAX object for DataTable

Tags: html, ajax, datatables

I'm using Ajax to populate my DataTable and it's working great:

```
$('#detailed').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "ajax": {
    "url": "./callToPHP.php?ID=" + jsID + "&DATE=" + jsdate,
    "dataSrc": "data"
    },
    "columns": [
        { data: "SEG_CODE" },
        { data: "START_MOMENT" },
        { data: "STOP_MOMENT" }
    ]
});
```

I was wondering how to go about adding an HTML element to these object like a chevron:

Can it be done in my js code or should I do it at the PHP level while I build my array?

Comment: I would suggest doing it when building the array

Comment: use column rendering -> **https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Examples**